# Баг после смены шрифта в TextArea (JavaFx)

Tags: java, javafx

Возникла проблема когда я писал блокнот на JavaFx:
при смене шрифта методом .setFont() Курсор остаётся с размером старого шрифта.
Вообщем на скриншоте и так всё понятно.

[image: Волки съели картинку]